# Testing Expect-CT reports

Tags: testing, report, certificate-transparency

I'm writing an Express route for [`Expect-CT`](http://httpwg.org/http-extensions/expect-ct.html) violations and I do not know how to create mock violations to trigger the [`report-uri`](http://httpwg.org/http-extensions/expect-ct.html#the-report-uri-directive) directive.

Is there a way to trigger this in-browser or through cURL / Postman?

My thoughts was to recreate the [JSON body of a report](http://httpwg.org/http-extensions/expect-ct.html#generating-a-violation-report) in Postman but surely there's a way to create more realistic test cases?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"json":{"data":"some data"}}' https://report.example.com/report-uri/
```

got from https://aaronhorler.com/articles/php-reporturi.html

all credits to aaron

Comment: The link gives 404